# Error clears my application's cache memory - android

Tags: android, opengl, android-fragments

I hope someone can help me solve the problem I´m having.

I am building an application for android that has two activities the first one asks for some basic information and the second activity let the user read some information from QR codes that I've created, this activity also has two fragments, the first one  displays a list of options and the second one displays some tables that are created dinamically everytime a QR code is read. At first it works just fine but sometimes, when the application finishes reading a code, it gives me the following error:

```
- E/OpenGLRenderer(32521): SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
```

This is the only error the LogCat shows.

When this error appears one of the things that happen is the app goes back to the MainActivity without giving any extra information, the second thing that happens is the app stays on the same activity but no information is displayed, this error appears to be clearing the cache of the app because when I try debugging, all the variables inside the activity have a value of null.